# Why did I get an error in __init__ saying that the "name" argument is missing even though I think there is no problem with the code I wrote

Tags: python-3.x

```
class Author():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.book = []
  
    def addBooks(self, *args):
        self.book += args

    def changeName(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def printDetails(self):
        print(f"Author Name:  Humayun Ahmed
        print("--------")
        print("List of Books:")
        for i in self.book:
            print(i)




auth1 = Author('Humayun Ahmed')
auth1.addBooks('Deyal', 'Megher Opor Bari')
auth1.printDetails()
print("===================")
auth2 = Author()
print(auth2.name)
auth2.changeName('Mario Puzo')
auth2.addBooks('The Godfather', 'Omerta', 'The Sicilian')
print("===================")
auth2.printDetails()
print("===================")
auth3 = Author('Paolo Coelho', 'The Alchemist', 'The Fifth Mountain')
auth3.printDetails()
```

[This is the expected output: Author Name:  Humayun Ahmed -------- List of Books: Deyal Megher Opor Bari =================== Default =================== Author Name:  Mario Puzo -------- List of Books: The Godfather Omerta The Sicilian =================== Author Name:  Paolo Coelho -------- List of Books: The Alchemist The Fifth Mountain

Comment: The error message is clear. What makes you think you're passing `name` in every call to `Author.__init__`?

Answer (score 1):

You did not pass name value to the variable `auth2`, you called empty constructor. 
Also, in `auth3`, you passed 3 strings when your constructor needs one, so it also will throw exception.